# HTTP node listen on AWS lambda using from my web site

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to create and app server on amazon AWS lambda servers?

Like this hello world function?

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write("Hello, this is Eric");
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

And how do I test it? And call it from my web site?

what is the URL of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda is a "Serverless" Computing platform. You can just write your response handler without setting up a server.

To do this, you would have to deploy your "Hello World" function to Lambda, and then configure it to respond to an Amazon API Gateway request. The Gateway receiving a request would be the "trigger" that causes your Lambda function to execute.

Alternatively, you could deploy your own server via EC2, but then there wouldn't be any point of using Lambda (in this case).

Try checking this the "Getting Started" guide on AWS - [Build an API to Expose a Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html).